# How do I deal with this scope issue?

Tags: c++

```
class Item {
    public:
        Item(int onHand, double cost, string name);
        void setName(string);
        string getName();
        void setCost(double);
        double getCost();
        void setonHand(int);
        int getonHand();
        void printMenu(vector<Item> & items);
    private:
        string name;
        int onHand;
        double cost;
};


class Denom {
    public:
        Denom(int onHand, double cost, string name);
        void setName(string);
        string getName();
        void setCost(double);
        double getCost();
        void setonHand(int);
        int getonHand();
    private:
        string name;
        int onHand;
        double cost;
};



void MenuFile(ifstream & Menu, string temp, string menu_strings[], vector<int> & Qnty, vector<double> & Price, vector<string> & itemName, string placeholder);
// void PickItem();

int main() {
    char x = 'T';
    int i;
    vector <Denom> money;
    vector<Item> items;
    vector<int> Qnty;
    vector<double> Price;
    vector<string> itemName;
    Denom Penny(50, 0.01, "Pennies"), Nickels(40, 0.05, "Nickels"), Dimes(50, 0.10,"Dimes"), Quarters(40, 0.25,"Quarters"), Dollar (10, 1.00, "Dollar"), Five(10, 5.00, "Five Dollars"), Ten(10, 10.00,"Ten Dollars"), Twenty(0, 20.00,"Twenty Dollars"), Fifty(0, 50.00,"Fifty Dollars"), Hundred(0, 100.00,"One Hundred Dollars");
    ifstream Menu;
    string menu_strings[15], temp, placeholder;
    MenuFile(Menu, temp, menu_strings, Qnty, Price, itemName, placeholder);
    for (i = 0; i < 11; i++)
    {
    Item MenuItem(Qnty[i], Price[i], itemName[i]);
    items.push_back(MenuItem);
    }
    do {
        cout << "X: " << endl;
        cin >> x;
    } while (x != 'Q');
    return 0;
}

void Item :: printMenu(vector<Item> & items)
{
    cout << "MENU" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
    {
        cout << items[i].getName() << " | " << items[i].getCost << " | " << items[i].getonHand << endl;
    }
}
```

So I give MenuItem the values in a constructor in the for-loop in main, but then I can't access it after that, which is a big problem, because I want to call MenuItem.printMenu(items) but it just won't let me because of scope.

My problem is that I need to declare it in the if statement to give those values 11 times, so what could I possibly do to call this method located in Item class?

Comment: You don't seem to have an if statement. And in your loops you are dealing with a vector that ends up with 11 elements. That vector has scope of almost all of main(). I don't understand what your difficulty is.

Comment: *"I want to call MenuItem.printMenu(items)"* -- on which of your 11 items? (If it doesn't matter which item is used -- because `printMenu()` intentionally [does not make use of `this`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static) -- then a better way to express your intent is that you want to call `Item::printMenu()`. The key difference is that the class is named instead of a particular object. The secondary difference is the syntax change from `.` to `::`.)

Comment: Why is the `Denom` class part of your [mre]? To make it easier for others to understand your question -- and to improve the odds of this helping someone else in the future -- you should remove all the code that is not necessary to present your situation. Simplify!